# Bootstrap will not display a column in 100%

Tags: layout, bootstrap-4

I am fighting with a bootstrap container which needs to get displayed in 100% heigth.

Example CodePen:

```
[https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OYPdgv][1]
```

Can anybode tell me whats going wrong with it? Has anybody a hint for me?

Regards
n00n

Comment: You need this style  html {
  height: 100%;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `<body>` on 100% height but you need `<html>` with 100% height yet:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

edited source: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/arzMaq

Comment: There is no way directly using a bootstrap class?

Comment: Of course, you can set `<html class="h-100">` and `<body class="h-100">` like in an "Bootstrap official example" on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer/